# Different Light Color

Tags: lighting

I wonder why after setting 3 different lights with 3 different light colors.  The light color changed into my last light color setting?

[image]

For example I set my last light color into yellow, then the other 2 light also turns into yellow.  Any clue why ?

Answer (score 1):

If you duplicate objects using Duplicate Linked(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) instead regular Duplicate(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), their data is shared. This means all data properties including light color.

...I suppose you could also accidently hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and choose Link Object Data, but that's probably not as likely as Duplicate Linked.

Select the lights and go to Object menu -> Relations -> Make Single User -> Object and Data to make data for each of the selected objects unique.

[image]

You could also use Blender's search(<kbd>F3</kbd>) and simply start typing the name of the command or even separate words that it includes:

[image]